# How to make a loop display each 14 lines but in order of pages?

Tags: php

I have a txt file with 119 numbers "7****",
what I do is to read them from beginning to end:

```
for($i = 119; $i >= 0; $i--){
```

In addition, I have to count every 14 lines.

Result:

```
28
72844
72845
72846
72847
72848
72997
72998
73000
73001
73002
73003
73004
73005
73006
14
73007
73083
73114
73123
73148
73149
73150
73151
73152
73188
73192
73193
73194
73195
0
```

with another loop inside:

```
if( $i % 14 === 0 ){
```

what I want to do is that instead of displaying 0 14 28, the loop will display 1 2 3 (type of pages):

```
2
72844
72845
72846
72847
72848
72997
72998
73000
73001
73002
73003
73004
73005
73006
1
73007
73083
73114
73123
73148
73149
73150
73151
73152
73188
73192
73193
73194
73195
0
```

My code:

```
for($i = 119; $i >= 0; $i--){

$lines = file("lines.txt");
$line = $lines["$i"];
echo "$line<br>";

if( $i % 14 === 0 ){
echo "$i<br>";
}

}
```

Comment: use the division operator `/`. Hint : `28 / 14 = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this works for you!

```
for($i = 119; $i >= 0; $i--)
{   
    $lines = file("lines.txt");
    if($i==119)
    {
    $no_of_lines = round(count($lines)/14); 
    }           
    
    $line = $lines["$i"];
    echo "$line<br>";

    if( $i % 14 === 0 )
    {       
    echo "$no_of_lines<br>";
    $no_of_lines--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and if i work with lines of numbers through a string and not a file, how will it be?
$lines = $mynumbers;

Comment: Having `$lines = file("lines.txt");` inside the loop will read the file each time it goes round the loop.

Comment: Yes Right, follow to write the code like this: $lines = file("lines.txt");->it must be before loop, so that it will not effect the looping performance!

Comment: For a string, generally i will use explode in php, check in stackoverflow some answers if it suitable for you!